# XSLT 2.0 Transformation using Saxon api in vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, xslt

I am trying to convert text file to xml in XSLT 2.0 using using Saxon.

```
text file = c:\\...\....sample.txt
```

For this, 
I want to pass an xml file which contains the path of the text file as attribute value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<InputArgs inputFile="C:\\...\....sample.txt" schemaName="test.xsd" />
```

I am using the code

```
        Processor proc = new Processor();
        XdmNode input = proc.NewDocumentBuilder().Build(new Uri(INPUT XML PATH));
        XsltTransformer transformer = proc.NewXsltCompiler().Compile(new Uri(INPUT XSL PATH)).Load();
        transformer.InitialContextNode = input;

        Serializer serializer = new Serializer();
        FileStream outStream = new FileStream(outFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        serializer.SetOutputStream(outStream);
        transformer.Run(serializer);
        outStream.Close();
```

i am getting error....

To conclude, how to transform a text file to xml
by providing xml and xsl only
The text file is passed as an attribute value in xml...

Something like passing parameter to XSL?

Comment: And the error message is? (including line number, and which line that is in the above code)

Comment: Telling us you are getting an error, without saying what the error actually is, is asking us to help you while blindfolded.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `file` URI in the form `<InputArgs inputFile="file:///C:/dir/subdir/sample.txt" schemaName="test.xsd" />`, then in XSLT you can use `unparsed-text`

```
<xsl:template match="InputArgs">
  <xsl:variable name="sample" select="unparsed-text(@inputFile)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Of course you can also define a parameter and pass in the URI if you prefer that.